# How to check if a value exists on a webpage with visual basic script

Tags: vbscript, hp-uft

I have been looking for a way to check a webpage for a date, if the date is there, then I want to progress with the loop otherwise exit the loop. I want to try and accomplish something like the below (please excuse my code, I am just starting out). However this does not seem to be the correct:

```
Dim DateToClick 
DateToClick = today

For i = 1 To 3
    '... some code ...

    If Browser("somebrowser").Page("somepage").Frame("someframe").WebTable("sometable").DateToClick.Exists = True 
    Then
        Browser("somebrowser").Page("somepage").Frame("someframe").WebTable("sometable").DateToClick.click 
    Else Exit For

        '... some more code ...

    End If
```

Is there any function within VB designed to check a web page for a value? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the code you have demonstrated, it looks as though you are searching through a `WebTable` object. In general, the easiest way to check if a value appears in such an object is to use the built in `GetRowWithCellText` method.

```
myRow = Browser("").Page("").Frame("").WebTable("myTable").GetRowWithCellText("20/09/2016")
```

The above code would set `myRow` to the number of the first row found containing specific text (in this case "20/09/2016").  You can use this row to then interrogate the rest of the table columns looking for any related data.  As you've indicated that you want to click on the item if it exists, I'd guess that the `WebTable` contains links.  If that is the case then you can simply set an object reference and then click it, like so:

```
Set myLink = Browser("").Page("").Frame("").WebTable("myTable").ChildItem(myRow, myCol, "Link", 0)
myLink.Click
```

You would need to set `myCol` in the above example to the column number the date appears in (indexed from 1).  What this does is creates an object that points to the first object of type `Link` held within the `WebTable` cell described by `myRow` and `myCol`, and then clicks on it.

Let me know if you require any further clarification, or if this isn't quite what you needed and I'll try to assist more.

Comment: Thanks very much for this. One question though - if the value of the specified text is not present on within the table, will the value of GetRowWithCellText be returned as 0 or as a null/ empty value?

Comment: I can't remember offhand if it returns 0 or -1 where the text is not found; a quick check of `If myRow<1 Then` will allow you to easily detect that no row with your text was found and handle it appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

In a Web Table  , you can fetch the column and row number for date column . 
 Then you can use.
  For column number spy for Web table and check for property "value"
  In value you will get all column names. try to get the column number for Date column then use below code.

For Iterator = 1 to row_count

var_Date = Browse("").Page("").Webtable("").GetCelldata(Iterator,colnum)

if var_Date = ""

Exit For
Next

2) If in case value is not present in table instead available on Page itself, then use below code :

2.1) If it WebEDit

var_Date = Browse("").Page("").Webedit("").getRopProperty("Value")

if var_Date = ""

Exit For

2.2) for Web Element use below code

```
   var_Date= Browse("").Page("").WebElement("").getRopProperty("title")

   if var_Date = ""
```

Exit For

Let me know for more information on this.

Comment: I'd advise you to use proper coding. You are missing `Then` in `If` clause, you are also missing `End If`, there is no such thing as `getRopProperty` (the correct is `GetROProperty`, with a single **p**), your code is not properly formatted, and for WebElement I believe it is actually better to use the `innertext` property, instead of `title`